# How to exclude a node from being indexed based on a field value?

Tags: 7, search

I would like to exclude some nodes from being indexed based on one field value (not content-type) on a drupal 7 installation, I can't find a hook letting me doing it, please help ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook to use is the following one:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_index_items_alter().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_search_api_index_items_alter(array &$items, SearchApiIndex $index) {
    foreach($items as $id => $item){
        if(isset($item->YOUR_FIELD) && $item->YOUR_FIELD[key($item->YOUR_FIELD)][0]['value'] == 'FORBIDDEN_VALUE') unset($items[$id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it clear to future readers: This code requires the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module.

Comment: I have tried this with Search API enabled and it does not work one bit.

Answer (score 3):

As [said in the API](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!search_api.api.php/function/hook_search_api_index_items_alter/7), using hook_search_api_index_items_alter is not the best choice.
You should use [hook_search_api_alter_callback_info](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api!search_api.api.php/function/hook_search_api_alter_callback_info/7)

Example :

```php
function mymodule_search_api_alter_callback_info() {
  $callbacks['exclude_some_nodes'] = array(
    'name' => t('Exclude some nodes'), 
    'description' => t('Exclude some nodes from being indexed based on one field value'),
    'class' => 'SearchApiExcludeSomeNodes',
  );
  return $callbacks;
}

class SearchApiExcludeSomeNodes extends SearchApiAbstractAlterCallback {

  public function supportsIndex(SearchApiIndex $index) {
    return $index->getEntityType() === 'node';
  }

  public function alterItems(array &$items) {
    foreach ($items as $k => $item) {
      if($item->field_your_field['und'][0]['value'] == 'do_not_index') {
        unset($items[$k]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This will appear as an option in the UI of Search API, in the Data alterations section (admin/config/search/search_api/index/your_index/workflow)

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder) module.

> Finder allows Drupal site administrators to create flexible faceted search forms to find entities such as nodes or users based on the values of fields and database attributes.

NOTE: Finder module is an Unsupported Project due to security issue as of October 14, 2008

Answer (score 1):

Use `hook_apachesolr_node_exclude()`.  An example implementation is given in the API doc:

```
/**
 * This is invoked by apachesolr.module for each node to be added to the index.
 * If any module returns TRUE, the node is skipped for indexing. Note that nodes
 * which are already present in the index and subsequently qualify to be
 * excluded will not be removed from the index automatically. This hook can be
 * used to remove them prior to returning TRUE.
 *
 * @param object $node
 *   The node object which is being indexed.
 * @param string $namespace
 *   Usually the calling module (eg. 'apachesolr_search').
 *
 * @return bool
 *   Return TRUE to skip the indexing of the node.
 */
function hook_apachesolr_node_exclude($node, $namespace) {
  // Exclude nodes from uid 1.
  if ($node->uid == 1) {
    apachesolr_delete_node_from_index($node);
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this hook, I have found this hook as well : hook_search_api_index_items_alter() which does the job, but I have noticed it is called several times for the same node, so maybe it is called for each fields of the node being indexed..? yours looks a better solution, will come back to give the right answer

Comment: oups, my bad, I don't have the apachesolr module installed, so I could not test your hook, thank you anyway ;)