# Exclude a node from being indexed with search_api

Tags: search

I've read over [How to exclude a node from being indexed based on a field value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/how-to-exclude-a-node-from-being-indexed-based-on-a-field-value) and I believe I've done exactly what it says. Yet, the nodes I don't want to have indexed are still in the index. Here's my code:

```
function mymodule_search_api_index_items_alter(array &$items, SearchApiIndex $index) {
  foreach($items as $id => $item){
    debugToFile("Looking at part " . $item->title);
    if(1 == preg_match("/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-/", trim($item->title))){
      debugToFile("   IGNORING ABOVE");
      unset($items[$id]);
    }
  }
}
```

Some notes: I want to exclude any node where the title starts with two capital letters followed by a hyphen. The `debugToFile` function does just that. Through it, I see that I am entering the if block when I should be: I see "   IGNORING ABOVE" just below all parts that *SHOULD* be blocked. However, after I blow away the index and reindex everything, I *STILL* have those nodes in the index.

Help??

Comment: Are you sure you purged indexes? Preventing node from getting into index does not automagically remove older data from index.

Comment: I wasn't sure. First I used the "Clear all indexed data" button to blow away everything in the index. Then I used "index now" to re-add everything back in. No dice: nodes with titles beginning (for example) "BE-" are in the index. I then took the nuclear option. In between clearing the index and reindexing the data, I stopped Solr, blew away the entire data directory (which gets recreated automatically), and restarted the Solr server. I AGAIN used the "Index Now" section of the search_api admin pages to reindex. Again, I see nodes in the results that I just shouldn't. Now I'm sure. :/